# Kafka CommitFailedException occurs when a breakpoint is used on a method annotated with @KafkaListener

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I do not understand why I get the CommitFailedException when I use a breakpoint on the method which is annotated with @KafkaListener.
I know for sure that I am not exceeding the metadata.max.age.ms = 300000 of the consumer and further more I am using `max.poll.records = 1`.
It seams like Heartbeat Thread is timing out but my understanding is that the Heartbeat Thread is independent from the poll thread.

I see that the following is condition is true in the AbstractCoordinator class a so the markCoordinatorUnknown() method is executed

```
else if (AbstractCoordinator.this.heartbeat.sessionTimeoutExpired(now)) {
  AbstractCoordinator.this.markCoordinatorUnknown();
}
```

I am using a spring-boot 2.3.5 which comes with kafka-clients-2.5.1 and IntelliJ 2019

Apologies if I do not provided detailed information about the entire setup but my goal is to see if other developers experience the same issue.
In production this issue it does not happen since (of course) the application is not running in debug mode :-)

Following is the error in the logs:

```
2021-03-03 12:26:13.830 ERROR 664 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1368) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1070) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1116) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:983) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1510) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2324) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2319) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2305) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2119) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1104) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1038) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.7.RELEASE.jar:2.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think IntelliJ suspends all threads by default, right click on the breakpoint and select `Thread` instead of `All`.

Comment: Yes! When I use the "Thread" everything is working as expected. Thank you very much Gary Russell